# Adding a second <%@Register %> line to my page causes Compilation Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I have just one <%@Register %> line in my page, it loads fine.

When I add a second one, it gives me this compilation error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The
>   type 'ASP.test1_ascx' exists in both
>   'c:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\c2d75602\aae4f906\App_Web_dta-e2tq.dll'
>   and
>   'c:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\c2d75602\aae4f906\App_Web_layerwindow.ascx.cdcab7d2.zxul1sik.dll'

(slightly anonymized)

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Additional information I just noticed: the line above the broken line in the YSOD said: [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()] When I searched for information on this, I found a page telling me to check to make sure I didn't have any open brackets I wasn't closing. Haven't found any yet, but this may be part of the issue.

**EDIT:** Argh. Just want to kill the computer at this point. After daughtkom suggested creating a new project to see if the code worked from scratch, I did that and it worked. I then decided to create a new control and copied the Test1 code into there... and then it started working. (No changes to Test1 or Default.aspx, just created Test1-2.ascx.) Then I added the link to Test2 into Default.aspx... and now it's giving me the same error, just with test2. And creating a Test2-2.ascx isn't fixing it this time.

Comment: Are both controls in the same namespace?

Comment: Yes, both controls are in the same namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up setting "<compilation batch="false">" in my web.config file, which fixed the issue. I found it from a MSDN article... somewhere. If I find the link again I'll post it.

Answer (score 6):

Delete your temporary files or restart your webserver.

Comment: I tried clearing the temporary files with no luck. I'm using the Visual Studio Development Server, so restarting that is no problem, but no luck there either.

Answer (score 0):

check the class names in test1.ascx.cs and test2.ascx.cs.

check the Inherits attribute of test2.ascx

Comment: Everything looks as it should; I'd c/p here, but I did a bunch of anonymizing (probably unnecessary) and it'd take time to clean it up. Short version, test1.ascx has codebehind test1.ascx.cs, and test1.ascx.cs is implementing "public partial class test1", and ditto with test2.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all of the DLLs in the folder mentioned in the error message.  Also, check to make sure that the code behind for test2.ascx.cs doesn't inherit from test1.

Comment: If you start a brand new project with just a page and two user controls do you get the same result?

Comment: No. *tries copying from the old project into the new project*

Comment: I copied over the entire Default.aspx, as well as the code for Test1 and Test2 and the codebehind for Test1, and it's working with no problems. (Looks like crap since I didn't bring over the other JS and CSS files, but the page loaded, which is more than I could say before.) I guess the next move is to remove the offending files and recreate them.